# What's the difference between EthOS and GenEthOs?

Tags: mining, ubuntu, linux, ethos

Both are mining distributions for Ether. [GenEthOs](https://ethereum-mining.info/en/) is free, EthOs is not. Both are based on Ubunut.

What's the difference between EthOS and GenEthOs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GenEthOS support usb, hdd, ssd and wi-fi ) preinstalled proxy and genoil miner

> **GenEthOS** Portable platform for Ethereum mining
>   The way the OS was designed by a miner for miners in the first place for those who see all perspectives decentralized platform Ethereum

--

> **ethOS** is a 64-bit linux distro that mines Ethereum out-of-the-box. ethOS is for large-scale deployment and its not free.

Answer (score 1):

**ethOS is free software**: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version, **as stated on their website**.